# How to create a linked list that points to the nodes of a binary tree?

Tags: c, loops, linked-list, binary-tree

I have a function that creates a binary tree, and for each node in the tree, I need to add a node to a separate linked list that points to the node in the binary tree.

My function to create the binary tree:

```
typedef struct myTree _node;

   

void INSERT(_node *(*tree), _node *item) { 
                    
     if (!(*tree)) {
          *tree = item;
          return;
     }
            
     if (item->val < (*tree)->val) {
          INSERT(&(*tree)->left, item);
     }
            
     else if (item->val > (*tree)->val) {
          INSERT(&(*tree)->right);
     }
 }
```

My main function:

```
int main(void) {

int i;
int *balanced;

_node *current, *root;
            
    root = NULL;
    
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        
        current = (_node *)malloc(sizeof(_node));
        current->left = current->right = NULL;
        current->val = balanced[i];
        INSERT(&root, current);
    }
    
return 0;
}
```

I've left out parts of my main function for simplicity.

The idea is that I want to print out the contents of the tree in pre, in, and post order, as well as traverse the linked list and print the value of the node in the tree that each linked list node points to.

I'm only a few months into learning C, so I am not terribly advanced.

Comment: While I haven't looked at the question yet, let me point out that your pointer declaration syntax is just strange. While declaring a double pointer as `int *(*foo)` is certainly valid, most people would declare thas as just `int ** foo` (or `int** foo` or `int **foo`, depending on their personal style). Also, don't use underscore-prefixed type names like `_node`, as they are reserved; while `struct myTree` is a perfectly good type name by itself, if you really must use a typedef, consider doing something like `node_t` or even just `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

Much like your insert function is recursive on the tree, walking the tree is recursive as well. There are two ways to do this: the specific way and the generic way. Let's see both.

The specific way just prints values as it encounters them. It solves this specific problem: printing the values. If you have to do tree walks to do more than one thing, you'd have to copy the code, which is generally a bad thing.
On the other hand, the code is much simpler and easier to follow. Let's look at the in-order case (you can do the other two by yourself; they are very similar):

```c
void print_in_order (const struct myTree * tree) {
  // if we're in a null node, do nothing
  if (!tree) return;
  // otherwise, do the left subtree, then the current node, then the right subtree
  // non-existent subtrees will be handled by the above check, so don't check twice
  print_in_order(tree -> left);
  printf("%d\n", tree -> val);
  print_in_order(tree -> right);
}
```

The generic way, on the other hand, is a better approach if your program is doing tree walks for all sorts of purposes. The idea is that you encapsulate the actual task to be done at each node (in this case, printing it) in a separate function:

```c
void print_node (const struct myTree * node) {
  printf("%d\n", node -> val);
}
```

And then you write a function that takes this function as an argument and calls it on each node, in the corresponding order. Let's do it for in-order:

```c
void apply_in_order (const struct myTree * tree,
                     void (* callback)(const struct myTree *)) {
  // this is the same as before...
  if (!tree) return;
  apply_in_order(tree -> left, callback);
  // ...except that, instead of doing a specific thing, we call the callback on each node
  callback(tree);
  apply_in_order(tree -> right, callback);
}
```

Now, you just call this function as `apply_in_order(tree, print_node);` and you get the same behavior as above. But the next time you need to write a function that walks a tree, you only need the per-node thing; the rest is already done.

Comment: It looks like this is a general solution for printing the contents of the tree, which is helpful, but not what I was looking for (I've got a working traverse routine already). What I need to do is create a separate linked list -- independent of the tree -- where each node in the linked list POINTS to a corresponding node in the tree.

Comment: The question was quite unclear in that regard, but the approach is the same. Just walk the tree, but instead of printing nodes, insert a node into your linked list when you walk each tree node.